# SQL Join x 3 tables

Tags: sql

```
SELECT C.FirstName, C.LastName, I.ID as InvoiceNbr, I.InvoiceDate, 
       I.GST, I.InvoiceTotal, I.GST + I.InvoiceTotal as TotalPayment
from Customer as C inner Join 
     Invoice as I
     On C.ID = I.ID inner Join 
     Payment as P
     On I.ID = P.InvoiceID
where I.ID is not null
```

;

Comment: Your question is lacking a question.

Comment: I just want to know why this isnt working for me ?i cant get the three table to join for some reason ?

Comment: What is the error you get? Btw: the `where I.ID is not null` is not needed as that is implied with your inner join to `customer`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the join between `customer` and `invoice` requires use of a foreign key in the invoice table.  It is **very unlikely** that `C.ID = I.ID' is correct. Something like this where I guessed the foreign key column name.:

```
SELECT
    C.FirstName
  , C.LastName
  , I.ID                   AS InvoiceNbr
  , I.InvoiceDate
  , I.GST
  , I.InvoiceTotal
  , I.GST + I.InvoiceTotal AS TotalPayment
FROM Customer AS C
INNER JOIN Invoice AS I ON C.ID = I.CustomerID --<< problem here
INNER JOIN Payment AS P ON I.ID = P.InvoiceID
WHERE I.ID IS NOT NULL
```